# Mix release "start_iex" shows error while "start" does not

Tags: elixir, release, elixir-mix

### Background

I am creating the release of an umbrella app via `mix release`. However, even though I can manually run the app, I get some errors when launching it.

### `mix release`

I am trying to run an app with `mix release`. This command works fine and it creates the executable in `_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app`. I can run this executable with the command `start` and everything runs nicely.

However, if instead of `start` I use `start_iex` I first get an error, and then the app runs normally:

```
$ _build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app start_iex
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
```

`my_app` is an umbrella app. Here is the `mix.exs` contents of the umbrella app:

```
defmodule MyApp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      apps_path: "apps",
      version: "0.1.0",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      elixir: "~> 1.10",
      releases: releases()
    ]
  end

  defp deps, do: []

  defp releases, do:
    [
      my_app: [
        applications: [
          api: :permanent,
          core: :permanent,
          storage: :permanent
        ]
      ]
    ]
end
```

### Question

1. Why do I get an error when using `start_iex` and not when using `start`?
2. Why does `start_iex` work after the error?

Comment: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/9164

Comment: Thanks! if you put that as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a race condition when you have shell history enabled. There's an open report [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2302).

> Because the disk_log is started after the user process, there
> is a chance for race conditions on shutdown, where disk_log will
> terminate before group, which will fail to log.
>
> Furthermore, if disk_log terminates BEFORE the shell starts,
> then the whole shell will fail to start, which will trigger
> another shell recursively, until the system finally shuts down.
> This can be reproduced with this command:
>
> `$ erl -kernel shell_history true -s init restart`